# ubuntu printer set up help

Tags: drivers, printing

I bought a new in the box HP "Office jet5258 All-in one" printer/scanner from a store and
when setting it up it said it does not recognize Linux. On HP's website I saw something about drivers that may have been developed since manufacture. I got lost when I tried it.
Is anybody familiar with this?

Comment: Does the printer not show up when you try to print something in libreoffice? If so, install hplip with `sudo apt install hplip`, and check if the printer is recognized when you print in libreoffice. For scanning, install xsane with `sudo apt install sane sane-utils libsane-extras xsane`, and check if the scanner is recognized in `xsane`.

Comment: *"I got lost when I tried it"* - What did you do exactly and what were the results? If you've already done some things, it's possible they need to be *reversed*, so it's important to know the complete history of what you've already tried.

Comment: Ubuntu version is also needed.

Comment: Forget about HPLIP. Installation of a network connected OfficeJet 5258 is absurdly easy. See https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting#Introduction and https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSQuickPrintQueues. Instructions for USB given on request.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. Other issues. after tearing my hair out I finally found (in  HP's